# @Html.Raw("<br />") vs "<br />"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor in ASP.NET MVC and realized that `@Html.Raw("<br />")` and `"<br />"` both put a break line in the html but was wondering what the actual difference between them is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Html.Raw` helper method allows you to insert a string of characters into the rendered HTML produced by your view.  It's useful when you want to insert text that might otherwise be interpreted by the Razor renderer:

```
<p>We can use <i>@Html.Raw("@Html.Raw(...)")</i> to force the Razor renderer to ignore things.</p>
```

On the other hand, Razor will already mostly ignore valid tags like `<br/>` without your intervention.  You can put a `<br/>` tag inline in your .cshtml page and it will render correctly in the HTML output.

The main side effect of using `@Html.Raw(...)` is that it produces additional code in the compiled view.  In principle `Raw(...)` could be optimized to produce exactly the same code as standard HTML, but more likely the output code will produce 3 string operations instead of 1 to handle that section of the code.

Personally I very rarely use `@Html.Raw(...)` because it doesn't normally make sense to do so.  I used it one time when Razor got confused over a complex conditional generation section in one of my pages and I just wanted it to shut the hell up about what it thought was an error, and a few times as a simple way to insert Razor code into a page.  And that's about it.